# React Native: image not visible

Tags: image, react-native, assets

Using React Native v0.61.5.
The images are visible (iOS and Android) in dev mode only on the emulator or on the phone attached with cable and Terminal running. Once I close the terminal and I open again the app the images are not visible.

Code for the image
`<Image source={require("../assets/image.png")} />`

Code I found for copy the images from the ./assets folder to /res:
 `npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/`

this code creates folders with the images I use but when I close the terminal and disconnect the phone the images are not visible.

Does it happen to you too? What should I do for be able to load the images without the terminal running?

Comment: just to be clear, the Shahid suggestion worked well. The command up here create different drawable folders renaming the files with _ and not - because are not accepted. So consider to edit your image name in your code too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should use a drawable folder in
   ProjectName/android/app/src/main/res directory for android and for
   ios use Images.xcassets drag and drop your images into this.
2. Add Images in this folder.
3. Access Image Like this `<Image source={{uri:"imagename"}}/>`

Comment: Don't forget to re run your project react-native run-android for android and react-native-run-ios for ios

Comment: Shahid, it worked. At the beginning on Andorid I received an error because the dash - was not accepted. Thank you for giving me the right key words ```drawable folder``` and ```Images.xcassets```. Have a nice day